# Update database with GET requests?

Tags: http, get, request, put

I've read online that you shouldn't update your database with `GET` requests for the following reasons:

- `GET` request is idempotent and safe
- violates HTTP spec
- should always read data from a server-database

Let's say that we have build a *URL Shortener service*. When someone clicks on the link or paste it at the browser's address bar it will be a `GET` request.

So, if I want to update, on my database, the stats of a shortened link every time it's been clicked, how can I do this if `GET` requests are idempotent?

The only way I can think of is by calling a `PUT` request inside the server's side code that handles the `GET` request.
Is this a good practice or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you're mixing up a few things here. 
While you shouldn't use `GET` requests to transfer sensitive data (as it is shown in the request URL and most likely logged somewhere in between), there is nothing wrong with using them in your use case. You are only updating a variable serverside.

Just keep in mind that the request parameter are stored in the URL when using `GET` requests and you should be ok.

Comment: That's too broad. The relevant thing is well explained in the HTTP spec, see https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7231.html#safe.methods